# Difference between two array which contains string and number

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I was able to find the difference between one array with another array (see the comparison between `a` and `c`). But the problem is if the array contains a number in one array. I've tried to do the following: `b.forEach(el=>{el.toString();});` or `a.forEach(el=>{parseInt(el, 10);});` with no avail.

```js
var a= ["473", "204"];
var b= [473, 204]; //problem is if number with string
var c= ["473", "204"];

console.log(a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n); }, new Set(b)));
console.log(a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n); }, new Set(c)));

b.forEach(el=>{el.toString();});
console.log(a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n); }, new Set(b)));

a.forEach(el=>{parseInt(el, 10);});
console.log(a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n); }, new Set(b)));
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to differentiate between two arrays which contain different type with 'same' value?

<sub>*Background: One of the array which was retrieved was from element `id` and the other is from the query.*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array in your `Set` to be numbers, and then when you use the `has` method you can coerce your string to a number using the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()):

```js
var a= ["473", "204"];
var b= [473, 204]; //problem is if number with string
var c= ["473", "204"];

var resB = a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(+n); }, new Set(b.map(Number)));
var resC = a.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(+n); }, new Set(c.map(Number)));

console.log(resB);
console.log(resC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
b.forEach(el=>{el.toString();});
```

and

```
a.forEach(el=>{parseInt(el, 10);});
```

are not doing anything at all - you're creating an expression with the string or number representation of the item, and then not doing anything with that expression. The original arrays remain unchanged.

To change the original array, you have to explicitly assign to it, eg

```
a.forEach((el, i) => {
  a[i] = parseInt(el, 10)
```

Or, even better, use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
var a= ["473", "204"];
var b= [473, 204]; //problem is if number with string
var c= ["473", "204"];

const aNums = a.map(Number);
console.log(aNums.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n); }, new Set(b)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use typeof

```js
console.log(typeof 42);
// expected output: "number"

console.log(typeof 'blubber');
// expected output: "string"

console.log(typeof true);
// expected output: "boolean"

console.log(typeof declaredButUndefinedVariable);
// expected output: "undefined";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to check if the set does not contain `n` as a number (`+n`) or `n` as a string (`n.toString()`):

```js
var a = ["473", "204"];
var b = [473, 204]; //problem is if number with string
var c = ["473", "204"];
var d = [473, "199", 175];

console.log(
   a.filter(function(n)
   {
       return !(this.has(+n) || this.has(n.toString()));
   }, new Set(b))
);
console.log(
    a.filter(function(n)
    {
       return !(this.has(+n) || this.has(n.toString()));
    }, new Set(c))
);
console.log(
    a.filter(function(n)
    {
       return !(this.has(+n) || this.has(n.toString()));
    }, new Set(d))
);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

Without using a `Set`, you can give a chance to **[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and the **[==](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality)** comparison.

```js
var a = ["473", "204"];
var b = [473, 204]; //problem is if number with string
var c = ["473", "204"];
var d = [473, "199", 175];

console.log(a.filter(n => !b.some(x => x == n)));
console.log(a.filter(n => !c.some(x => x == n)));
console.log(a.filter(n => !d.some(x => x == n)));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the double equals (aka Abstract Equality Comparison) operator for type coercion:

```
console.log(473 == '473') // true
```

[MDN reference on JS equality comparisons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)